# Developing a GUI with PySide

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyside

I am trying to get buttons and a menu bar inside a GUI application. When I run my code the GUI is seen with the menu bar but the button is not seen. Here is my sample code. And the code compiles without any error.

```
import sys
from PySide.QtGui import *
from PySide.QtCore import *

class guiwindow(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super(guiwindow,self).__init__()

        self.menubar()

    def menubar(self):
        textEdit = QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(textEdit)

        exitAction = QAction('Exit', self)
        exitAction.setShortcut('Ctrl+Q')
        exitAction.setStatusTip('Exit application')
        exitAction.triggered.connect(self.close)

        self.statusBar()

        menubar = self.menuBar()
        fileMenu = menubar.addMenu('&File')
        fileMenu.addAction(exitAction)

        self.setGeometry(400, 100, 1200, 800)
        self.setWindowTitle("Menubar + Buttons")


        button = QPushButton("Test")
        hbox = QHBoxLayout()
        hbox.addStretch(1)
        hbox.addWidget(button)
        self.setLayout(hbox)  
        self.show()


def main():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = guiwindow()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally, in GUI programming you'll have to be faimliar with the concept of parent and child widgets. If you want your button to be inside your window, then the later should be a child of the former.

So use:

```
button = QPushButton("Test", parent=self)
```

Instead of:

```
button = QPushButton("Test")
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: could you please tell some good tutorials/documentation that I can go through to learn more. This works but the button appears seems to be overlapping on the File option of the menu bar. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: @RaghavendraMG That's probably because you need to set the layout to your central widget instead of the main window (this is not allowed by Qt). So it should be `textEdit.setLayout(hbox)` instead of `self.setLayout(hbox)`. However consider changing that `textEdit` with something like `centralWidget`.